# jQuery BlockUI not working when called twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, blockui, jquery-blockui

I'm using [jQuery BlockUI Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) on page loading (first thing):

```
<script>
    $.blockUI({ message: null });
</script>
```

And when everything loads, the whole page unblocks:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $.unblockUI();
});
```

It works fine, but then I can't block ui again like this:

```
$("#buttonFoo").click(function(){
    $.blockUI(); //nothing happens
    doStuff(); //I want screen blocked while doing stuff
    $.unblockUI();
});
```

doStuff() is called but screen not blocked. Should I do anything else?

[EDIT]

It worked but as @GuruprasadRao said, **$.unblockUI()** didn't wait for doStuff() to finish. I solved like this:

```
$("#buttonFoo").click(function(){
      $.blockUI({
        onBlock: function() {
            doStuff();
            $.unblockUI();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Any `console errors`?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao no, console's not throwing anything.

Comment: It works but I suspect you are not able to view it since `$.unblockUI();` might not wait until your ajax request `doStuff()`

Comment: Yeah, it was that. I'll edit the question with the solution. Thanks @GuruprasadRao

Comment: Add it as answer and accept it.. Otherwise the question would be deleted..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked but as @GuruprasadRao said, `$.unblockUI()` didn't wait for `doStuff()` to finish. I solved like this:

```
$("#buttonFoo").click(function(){
      $.blockUI({
        onBlock: function() {
            doStuff();
            $.unblockUI();
        }
    });
});
```